# Images blurry and crispy in Internet Explorer - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I have a problem with images being blurry and crispy in internet explorer. Sometimes it happens in Edge too. I first thought it was because some of the images was being resized by the browser, but I have tested it without forcing the browser to resize and than does not trigger the problem.

Anyone got any ideas how to fix this?

[See examples here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgeZT.jpg)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Its hard to help without really seeing any code.